# Magento2 : getChildHtml('', true)

Tags: magento2

In view file what does this stand for :

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
```

From where this get the child html

Comment: it means render all child block HTML.

Comment: there is lot of child block , then which one block is render?

Comment: it will render all children block  whihc are under the current block For Ex. `product.info.addtocart`

Comment: this line of code  in this path 
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml   

so which block is render ,, can you explain it ?

Comment: I have explained it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see `product.info.options.wrapper` have two children in `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
```

in hte XML `product.info.options.wrapper` block have two children:

1. `product.info.options`
2. `html_calendar`

that's why they used `<?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>` in `product/view/options/wrapper.phtml` file also we can add our custom option or block for more Options that's why they are rendering all child.

Even Magento adding some option for the bundle without overriding that PHTML file in `/vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml`